# Hex to String conversion does not work

Tags: java, hex

I have this hex `ffeeddcc` that I want to convert to readable String.
I am using online converters to do that.

Some of the converters do not convert at all (http://chxo.com/scripts/hex2string.php), and some yield `ÿîÝÌ` (http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx)

Any ideas ?

Comment: What exactly is your idea of a "readable String" in this case?

Comment: "I am using online converters to do that." => What's that? Could you provide a code example....

Comment: @piet.t for example I enter `796f755f6172655f616e5f6964696f74` (not readable) and the conversion website gives me `you_are_an_idiot` (readable).

Comment: So what would you expect the output to be for `ffeeddcc`? Those are no standard ASCII-codes!

Comment: @piet.t I think this is it. Those were not standard ASCII codes,, you can post it as an answer and I would accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The simple method which you can try is this:

```
String h = "ffeeddcc";    
byte[] b = Hex.decodeHex(h.toCharArray());
System.out.println(new String(b, "UTF-8"));
```

Also refer **[Hex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html)**

Another approach

```
  public String convertHexToString(String hex){

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

      //796f755f6172655f616e5f6964696f74 split into two characters 79, 6f, 75...
      for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){
          String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
          int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
          sb.append((char)decimal);
          temp.append(decimal);
      }
      System.out.println(temp.toString());

      return sb.toString();
  }
```

**EDIT:**

As piet has said, I confirmed that those were not the standard ASCII codes and hence you were getting the issue. If you will use the standard ASCII codes it will work.

Comment: I tried this, (after downloading the JAR file from apache commons).. it gives me `????` which is equivalent of the random characters from the website I assume.

Comment: @tony9099:- Updated my answer with another approach. Please check now!

Comment: @tony9099:- Yes as piet has said, I also checked, those were not standard ASCII-codes and hence you were getting the issues. (*got puzzled*). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A possible implementation with plain Java.

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("796f755f6172655f616e5f6964696f74");
 while (sb.length() >= 2) {
      System.out.print((char)Integer.parseInt(sb.substring(0, 2), 16));
      sb.delete(0, 2);
 }
```

The implementation is quite naive, means there are places for optimization.